# passing individual array elements to a function which takes the address of the array as input

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose we have a function `f1` with definition,

```
void f1(double in,int n,double* out)
```

Now I wish to pass individual elements of an array as the 3rd input of `f1` from another function `f2`.

```
void f2(double* in,int size,int n,double* out)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        f1(in[i],n,&(out[i]));
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? If not, what is the correct way?

Comment: Just remember if you are sending `myFunction(array[i])`, you are sending a **copy** of the value at the index `i`. If you call `myFunction(&array[i])`, you are sending a **pointer** to the value. Which means you could now modify the real value in the array, not a copy. By doing : `*value = newValue;`.

Comment: `void f1(double in,int n,double* out)` 
`f1(in[i],n,&(out[i]));` is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the correct ways.

Comment: If I am passing it in this way, i.e by f1(in[i],n,&(out[i])), the output is coming as a recursive sum. For example, if I pass 5,4, the ans is coming 5 and 9. How can I solve this problem?